# Unknown database type oid requested

Tags: php, database, symfony

I am very new to symfony (first day reading through it). I am trying to create a table from a class. I successfully created the class with the command

`php bin/console make:entity`.

here is the class:

```
<?php
namespace App\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\DbUserRepository")
 */
class DbUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $role;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150, nullable=true)
     */
    private $names;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRole(): ?string
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    public function setRole(?string $role): self
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNames(): ?string
    {
        return $this->names;
    }

    public function setNames(?string $names): self
    {
        $this->names = $names;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Now, I am supposed to run the command `php bin/console make:migration`

The error I m getting is:

> 2019-02-22T16:05:42+02:00 [error] Error thrown while running command "make:migration". Message: "Unknown database type oid requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\PostgreSQL92Platform may not support it."
>
> In AbstractPlatform.php line 423:
>   Unknown database type oid requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\PostgreSQL92Platform may not support it.

There is no type `oid` there, so why this error?

Comment: Did you make the database yet? `bin/console doctrine:database:create`

Comment: Yes! the database exists

Answer (score 0):

```yaml
dbal:
    schema_filter: ~^(?![^\.]*\.)~
```

OR

```yaml
dbal:
    schema_filter: ~^(?!buckardo\.)~
```

This option excludes the processing of tables not from the main database schema. (such as buckardo)